# How does Ruby know when '/' is a divide symbol, vs. when it starts a regular expression?

Tags: ruby, regex, lexical-analysis

I'm working on a lexer for Ruby.   Such a lexer needs to clearly
distinguish divide '/' operators from regex /..../  operands.

Lexers are nicest to build when they are context free (stateless)
with respect to lexing-the-next token.

Some program text that starts with "/" might be:

```
    ...  / abc*(foo(def,bar[q-z]*)+sam) / ...
```

You can't tell if the '/' symbol is a divide or the start of regexp.

So clearly Ruby must be looking at the context, or it must have rule
to decide when it is ambiguous.  What's the rule?

[one possibility: it only allows them where divide cannot occur, e.g, after

```
when  [   (   ,    #{  {  if  elseif   !=  =    !~   +    ,  <<  and  or not
```

(Edit 8/24/2015: extended the above list)

Does that cover everything? Or it is something entirely different?]

Comment: No, it doesn't, at least after a method name `/` can mean either divide or regex start.

Comment: Ruby parsing is hard. I assume this is to add to your company's toolchain?

Comment: I fear you don't know what you got yourself into. Yes, [it isn't stateless](https://ruby-hacking-guide.github.io/contextual.html) but it also looks at the next character (to decide if it's the `/=` operator or ambiguous): [gaze into the abyss](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_3/parse.y#L8379-L8397).

Comment: @DaveNewton  Yes.  (Parsing C++ is hard, and we do that, so "hard" doesn't scare me much).

Comment: @cremno I can handle state in the lexer.   *Next* character?  That sure doesn't help for the example.

Comment: The "isn't stateless" link is great, an unexpected bonus answer to my question.

Comment: I hope it didn't come of as me being rude towards you. If you look the linked code you'll see what I meant. There was also a reference to [this blog post](http://programmingisterrible.com/post/42432568185/how-to-parse-ruby). Another good resource might be the [lexer source code](https://github.com/whitequark/parser/blob/master/lib/parser/lexer.rl) in Ragel of the excellent `parser` gem.

Comment: @cremno  No, didn't interpret as rude.  Was hoping for more insight than "see this squirming mess? It does it somehow" though; I had looked at the Ruby implemenation once a long time ago.   One lesson we've learned building lots of front ends: just because an existing implementation is mess, doesn't mean yours has to be, so I didn't want to copy what was done without understanding why.

Comment: Just for grins, I tried the following heuristic:  lex a construct at this point in the source as a regex, if you can find a valid regex starting at this point.  (This sounds stupid, but in fact we lex regexes not as a single "string" but in terms of the regular expression actions inside the regex).   I was hoping that regexes had enough constraints to eliminate non-regexes.  Not suprisingly, this was as complete failure.  Any math code sequence <formula> / <moremath> /  pretty much matches this and produces false positives.  Oh, well, it was a cheap experiment.  [Note progress in other answer]

Comment: @cremno: I looked at the Ragel lexer http://github.com/whitequark/parser/blob/master/lib/parser/lexer.rl    It seems to keep track of the position of the input stream wrt grammar ("begin expression").   But I don't see how implements hek2mgl's rule of ARG / ARG.   Do you believe his rule?  How does Ragel do it (what did I miss)?

Comment: The rule is in another file: https://github.com/whitequark/parser/blob/v2.2.2.6/lib/parser/ruby22.y#L681 (It's also just a pseudo BNF from 1998.)

Comment: @cremno: Do you believe Borsunho's assertion above? Do you beleive that implies that Ruby actually encounters amibiguous parses such as my example, and resolves the ambiguity at lexing time?  Do you believe hek2mgl's assertion about ARG / ARG?  Does that psuedo BNF implement that assertion?  I looked briefly at the psuedo BNF but couldn't see any evidence of this.  (I don't trust psuedo BNFs much, if psuedo means "not an actual implementation"; by definition, such things don't actually work and it is easy to handwave away problems by simply not addressing them or in some offhand comment)

Comment: (I'm not an expert.) 1) If `/` directly follows a method name, then it's div.: `x/y` is okay, `x/y/` is a syntax error (no divisor). `x/ y` is div., `x /y` is a syntax error (regexp beg.). 2) It tries to(?). 3) Why not? That rule exists. 4) I don't know.

Comment: Added a correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

The Ruby lexer emits completely different tokens for a division operator and for the start of a regex (one is `'/'`, the other `tREGEXP_BEG`). So the parser has no idea that the two actually use the same source text.

How does the lexer know which token to emit? See `parse.y:8451` from the Ruby source.

The `parser_params` struct which is passed to the lexer has a member called `lex.state`. This is a bitfield, with each bit indicating something about the lexer state. The individual bits are called `BEG`, `END`, `ENDARG`, `ENDFN`, `ARG`, `CMDARG`, `MID`, `FNAME`, `DOT`, `CLASS`, `LABEL`, and `LABELED`.

When the lexer sees a `'/'` character, it emits `tREGEXP_BEG` *if*...

1. The lexer state is true for both `ARG` and `LABELED`, or
2. The lexer state is true for any one of `BEG`, `MID`, or `CLASS`.

Otherwise, it emits a division operator token.

So what do the states actually mean? The Ruby source contains the following comments on them:

```
EXPR_BEG_bit,       /* ignore newline, +/- is a sign. */
EXPR_END_bit,       /* newline significant, +/- is an operator. */
EXPR_ENDARG_bit,        /* ditto, and unbound braces. */
EXPR_ENDFN_bit,     /* ditto, and unbound braces. */
EXPR_ARG_bit,       /* newline significant, +/- is an operator. */
EXPR_CMDARG_bit,        /* newline significant, +/- is an operator. */
EXPR_MID_bit,       /* newline significant, +/- is an operator. */
EXPR_FNAME_bit,     /* ignore newline, no reserved words. */
EXPR_DOT_bit,       /* right after `.' or `::', no reserved words. */
EXPR_CLASS_bit,     /* immediate after `class', no here document. */
EXPR_LABEL_bit,     /* flag bit, label is allowed. */
EXPR_LABELED_bit,       /* flag bit, just after a label. */
```

Whenever the lexer emits a token, depending on the current lexer state, the token which was lexed, and possibly what the lexer sees next in the source text (it does look ahead in a number of places), it may move to a new state.

Some of the states are only entered after lexing a reserved keyword. For example, `EXPR_MID` is entered after lexing `break`, `next`, `rescue`, or `return`.

Comment: Just now discovered your answer, I really appreciate your chiming in. I don't know if this is the truth but it has the ring of authority.  +1 until I discover otherwise +} accept if I get to test this out and it works.  [Are all these bits derived ONLY from the lexer state?]

Comment: "It has the ring of authority..." Well, this was based on reading the Ruby lexer code. If you have any doubts, you can download it and read it too. BTW, if you want to see the tokens which the Ruby lexer emits, you can use this in `irb`: `require 'ripper'; Ripper.lex('ruby code here')`

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the way how the parser is defined. Having a look at [BNF definition of Ruby](http://docs.huihoo.com/ruby/ruby-man-1.4/yacc.html) you can see that the division operation (in the `ARGS` section) is defined before the definition of a `REGEXP`. That's why the division operation has a higher precedence than a regexp.

Meaning, if the ruby parser stumbles upon a section that resolves to

```
ARG / ARG
```

it will treat it as a division and goes further.

Walking trough a [flex/bison tutorial](http://aquamentus.com/flex_bison.html) will enlighten you! (Plus it is a fun)

Comment: Yes, I knew it worked because of Ruby's parser; I've long heard "only Ruby can parse Ruby".  But that doesn't really tell you anything.  I've also heard repeatedly that parsing C++ using a parser generator doesn't work; that's simply wrong (our tools do it).   I think I know about flex and bison well enough.    I'll look at @cremno's link "gaze into the abyss" to try to understand what they did.   The purpose of my question here was to find out if there was a simple abstract rule.

Comment: So, how does my example resolve? It appears to require infinite lookahead, which flex does badly.

Comment: Following the BNF, it depends on `...` (the code before the /) . Isn't it?

Comment: In essence what this BNF says is, "allow a regexp where it is allowed".  Its generally inconvenient for a lexer to consult the grammar.   However, our parsers have that capability so I think I can fall back to that, augmenting the easily-done previous token check for clear indication places (e.g., my proposed set of lead-in tokens in my question).  The token-check seems to work remarkably well in practice; I can lex all but 69 files out of the 5180 that make up MetaSploit (a nice big example) with just that hueristic, and I have yet to implement some of the more arcane interpolated constructs.

Comment: The lexer doesn't deal with the BNF, it simply produces a stream of terminal symbols and literals. `/` is a literal.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with the essential architecture of lexers. (Check my bio).  The issue here is that lexing a regex requires the lexer to know that a "/" must, at this point in the source stream, be a lead-in to the regex body.   And that *in the abstract*, even you made this point, requires consulting the grammar.  How that consultation is realized in a particular lexer depends on what it can do.   Asking the parser if a regex "is acceptable now" is in effect inspecting the BNF.

Comment: @Borsunho's comment to my question makes it clear that even asking the parser doesn't solve the problem.   So, Ruby must have an ambiguity resolution rule; you state it as "if it looks like ARG / ARG then it is division"  Where is that rule documented?   That's quite a neat trick for a lexer to accomplish, because it amounts to parsing the text for ARG before committing to a choice.  Do you know how ruby does that or do I have to dig it out of the implementation?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP is asking about the Ruby lexer, not the parser.